# Using value returned by php function in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a simple function  returning the title of an external webpage.

```
public function actionGetUrl($url)

    {
        $str = file_get_contents($url);
    // index of the opening-tag + the length of needle
        $openTag = strpos($str,"<title>") +7;
    // index of the ending tag
        $endTag = strpos($str,"</title>");
    // extract the bit between
        $title = substr($str, $openTag, ($endTag - $openTag));


       return $title;

    }
```

in my jquery function, I have the following,

```
$(document).ready(function(){                     
        $(function(){
            $("#grabUrl").click(function(e){
                $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('post/geturl', array('url' => 'http://bbc.co.uk')); ?>",


                success: function(data) {               
                strang= String(data);                       
                    alert(strang);
                }   

            });
        });
    });
});
```

The alert  displays  nothing.  $title  contains  'BBC Homepage' in this case.

Is anyone see where I made a mistake?

Thank you for your help

Comment: try `console.log(data)` before the alert and see if you're getting anything on the console. also check if you're getting any errors on the console.

Comment: just echo your result in ajax. return is not used in ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ajax so from php do no return but `echo $title;`.

```
public function actionGetUrl($url)

{
    $str = file_get_contents($url);
// index of the opening-tag + the length of needle
    $openTag = strpos($str,"<title>") +7;
// index of the ending tag
    $endTag = strpos($str,"</title>");
// extract the bit between
    $title = substr($str, $openTag, ($endTag - $openTag));


   echo $title;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming what ever you are doing in PHP function is correct. you don't have to return the data in php , just echo the response.

```
 public function actionGetUrl($url)
 {
    $str = file_get_contents($url);
// index of the opening-tag + the length of needle
    $openTag = strpos($str,"<title>") +7;
// index of the ending tag
    $endTag = strpos($str,"</title>");
// extract the bit between
    $title = substr($str, $openTag, ($endTag - $openTag));


   echo $title;
}
```

Comment: weclome , glad it helped.. happy coding :)